# How to find 30 days older epoch time in ms from current time in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp, epoch, milliseconds

How do I find epoch time of 30 days from current time in shell script? If my current time is X in epoch milliseconds.Then I need epoch milliseconds of 30 days older in shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
current=$(date +'%s%3N')
echo $current
oldtimestamp=$((current - 30*24*60*60))
echo "old is $oldtimestamp"
```

This doesnt seem to give 30 days old epoch ms. Please let me know how to get it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You've calculated 30 days in seconds; you need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Comment: That means: `oldtimestamp=$((current - 30*24*60*60*1000))`

Comment: Great , Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command supports some natural language expressions:

```sh
date  +'%s%3N' --date='30 days ago'
```

Of course, this will be some milliseconds off when compared to `${current}` because of the time it takes to execute these commands themselves, but perhaps it's close enough for you.

Otherwise, the correct arithmetic expression is what Jonathan Leffler wrote:

```
oldtimestamp=$((current - 30*24*60*60*1000))
```

but note that things like leap seconds may throw you off in that approach.